# Как сделать стрелки прокрутки карусели, выходящие за сетку Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap, carousel

Здравствуйте! Помогите советом. Как можно сделать стрелки для owl carousel, которые выходят за сетку bootstrap (в проекте использую чисто сетку bootstrap). Т.е у меня карусель на `col-md-12`, а стрелки выходят за сетку на макете. Есть варианты?

Вот скрин макета: http://uploads.ru/qWtaR.png

Вот разметка:

```
<section class="slider-wrap">

    <div class="slider-nav-container">
    <div class="slider-nav">
        <div class="prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        <div class="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12">
           <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

         <!-- Slide Start -->
           <div class="item">
           <div>
            <h2>WE THINK CREATIVE BE CREATIVE</br>
            LIKE TO DO CREATIVE WORKS</h2>
            </div>
                 <div class="scroll">
            <div><i class="pe-7s-mouse"></i></div>
            <div>Scroll down</div>
        </div>
                </div>
            <!-- Slide End -->
         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: если это Вы задавали вопрос и Вы же делаете правку, то Вам необходимо объединить учетные записи. О том как это сделать прочтите [**здесь**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слайдер ставите в *container*. 
 Перед слайдером стрелку *влево*, после слайдера стрелку *вправо*.
Это все выглядит примерно так: 
**HTML**:

```
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="left-arrow"><img src="/arrow-l.png"></div>
    <div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"> 
    slider content
    </div></div></div>
    <div class="right-arrow"><img src="/arrow-r.png"></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**, для позиционирования стрелок:

```
.left-arrow,.right-arrow{
padding-top: /*нужное значение */;
}
```

Так же можно сделать в *container-fluid*:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <div class="left-arrow"><img src="/arrow-l.png"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10"> 
             slider content
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <div class="right-arrow"><img src="/arrow-r.png"></div>
        </div>
    </div></div>
```

**CSS** тот же.

Comment: Спасибо большое! У меня получилось. Правда, код css сделал очень стремно.Паддинги огромные.Мне интересно это плохая верстка или по другому нельзя было.Все пытался, но ничего не двигалось, пока я не смирился с таким вот кодом: .slider-wrap
 position: static
 .prev
  position: absolute
  padding-top: 265px
  padding-left: 150x
  font-size: em(100px)
  color: lighten($main-color, 50%)
 .next
  position: absolute
  font-size: em(100px)
  color: lighten($main-color, 50%)
  .fa
   position: absolute
   bottom: 340px
   left: 1250px

Comment: @Safbek, если не используете препроцессоры, то советую обязательно переходить уже сейчас на них (Sass) ;)
Есть один миксин, который я регулярно использую для центрирования элемента (в т.ч. и вертикального, чертов vertical align никогда не работает). Попробуйте использовать sass и изучите миксины (это очень просто, но оооочень упрощает работу с css).

Comment: Ep1demic Я недавно начал пользоваться sass  и пока очень плохо знаком с его возможностями( Но, надеюсь, по-тихонечку да и изучу. И да, vertical align не сработал никак. А можете поделиться этим миксином?)) если это возможно

Comment: @Safbek, https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/centering-mixin/

Comment: Ep1demic Премного благодарен!)

Answer (score 0):

Без исходника получается какая-то игра в угадайку, но попробую предложить.

Элементы со стрелками заверните в обертку, установите ей атрибут `position: static`. Это нужно для того, чтобы обнулить настройки стилей позиционирования, применимых в bootstrap. К самим стрелкам, не знаю, в каком теге они у вас расположены, но к ним (по id, например) применяйте атрибут `position: absolute`, а так же артибутами `left top right bottom` указывайте расположение относительно окна браузера.

Материалы для изучения:

http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/blochnaya-verstka/pozitsionirovanie-elementov
http://htmlbook.ru/css/position

Comment: Спасибо, что отозвались!